# Inovua ReactDataGrid column filter context menu does not always open with one click on the column filter icon

Tags: reactjs, filter, datagrid, contextmenu

I used Inovua ReactDataGrid to display a data table with a header row and column filters. Each column filter has a filter icon, and a click on each normally displays a column filter context menu which allows to select the type of filter (e.g. for a string filter one can choose between "contains", "starts with", "ends with", ...).
A problem arises when one clicks on a filter icon, selects a filter type (e.g. "contains" for a string filter), and after that clicks on the same filter icon again. In that case, the filter context menu does no open. One needs to click once again on the filter icon (so in total twice) to open the filter context menu once again.
Does anyone how why this happens or how to change the behaviour such that one needs to click only once on the filter icon to display the filter context menu once again?

It would also help to know how to open the filter context menu programmatically. In that case, I would be able to write a workaround. Does anyone know how to do that?

I was able to render a custom filter icon and use an event handler for the custom filter icon to know when one clicks on the icon but I was not able to open the filter context menu programmatically after that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found a solution for the problem. There already exists [an issue](https://github.com/inovua/reactdatagrid/issues/300) in the reactdatagrid Github repository which describes the problem I had and which is solved in reactdatagrid 5.x.x. As I used reactdatagrid 4.x the problem arosed to me. I simply updated to the current version 5.8.0 and the problem was gone.